# Tab switching in tab control takes lot of time, if all tree view nodes are in expanded state

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, tabcontrol

I have a tab control and the tabs inside it contain a tree view. If I keep all the nodes of the tree view in an expanded state, then the switching of the tabs become very slow. But if the tree view is completely in collapsed state, then there is no problem in switching of tabs.

Is there any way that the tree view remains in expanded state and the tabs are responsive. I have tried several options from online resources including implementation of Non Reloading Tab Control etc.. but there was no benefit. The only thing that works is using a completely collapsed tree view.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems strange to me, are you sure you don't have some failing binding on expanded node that slow down things?

Comment: No. If binding fails, then how would the tree view work. It is showing all the nodes perfectly, but just the loading of tab after switching takes time.

Comment: I wasn't talking about treeview binding, but about eventually node item ones.